# SelectorRegionAdapter and TabControl: How to correctly use it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, prism-4

I am using Prism 4 and I am trying to figure out how to use a TabControl as a region.  The documentation says that SelectorRegionAdapter would be used as the region adapter for it.  My main questions are about adding the views.

1. How does the adapter determine the header for the view's TabItem?
2. How can I control what the TabItem's header would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter does NOT generate a header for the TabItem.  The UserControl view becomes the TabItem.Content.  To generate the header, you have to create a Style and set the Header there in relation to the View under the Content property.  Then you bind this style to the `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` property on your tab control.  When you add views to the Region that is bound to the TabControl, a TabItem is created, using the style specified in the ItemContainerStyle property, setting the Header as specified in the Style.